# Returning back to the original report via a return link button in the linked report with multiselect params in the main report

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I am working with ssrs reports. I have a summary and a detailed report. The detailed report is linked to the summary report. Now the user wants to have a "Return to Summary Report" link in the detailed report.

My main problem is I have multiselect parameters in the Summary report. I know the solution if I have single select parameters. In that case I can create a textbox with text decorated as link button and in the Action property of the textbox I choose Jump to report and provide paramaters which I get from the previous report. This method works for single select parameters in the summary but I dont know how to handle the multi select.

Also we do not have the small button that ssrs provides to go back to reports. So thats not an option I can use.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the Action property Ihad to select the "Jump to URL" option and put this in the textbox for Jump to URL:

```
="javascript: history.go(-1)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is whre you have to place  javascript:history.back(1)

- right click on the report
- click insert -> textbox
- once the text box is created
- right click and choose "Text box properties"
- click  "Action" property
- choose Go to URL option button

copy and past javascript:history.back(1)

(Note: it is case sensitive, you don't need to put quotation mark")

then click ok  and this should be working in IE